# How to change the width of column in datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

It looks like an easy question, but somehow I can not find the right answer. I have datagrid in wpf in which I want to change the width of columns in c#. The  code is

```
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    DataColumn col1 = new DataColumn("From", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add(col1);
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("To", typeof(string)));
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Occurrence", typeof(int)));

    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
```

But DataColumn has no width option. How to change the width of column in this case? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the right solution. Just add

```
    dataGrid1.ColumnWidth = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

DataColumn is only for data and is not a WPF object, which is why it doesn't have a width.

You can set the width on the columns on dataGrid1

```
dataGrid1.Columns[0].Width = 50;
```

...however if you have AutoGenerateColumns set to true this may not work, and besides that styling in C# code is not good practice.

The best approach for full control is to use XAML and binding each column to the datagrid. This site has a great guide to datagrids and binding http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html